# $.get() returns string while fetching JSON file (Only in Mac)

Tags: json, ajax

My JSON is a standard key value pair e,g

```
{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2"}
```

in a separate file, and is fetched using

```
$.get()
```

The datatype of the response as expected is in JSON. But, in case of mac, the datatype of the response is String.

I need help to figure out why is this discrepancy.

PS - This issue can easily be resolved by "if" statement on datatype check. This question is to figure out why such datatype change could occur.

Comment: You could explicitly set `dataType` as "json" in the $.get() options to force jQuery to always parse the response as JSON. Otherwise it may depend on whether the server sets the content type header correctly in the response, and whether the browser takes any notice of that. Or try `$.getJSON()` to achieve the same thing

Comment: P.s. is this on a specific browser on Mac? I'd expect an issue like this to be browser specific rather than operating-system specific? What browser and what version of the browser is affected, exactly?

Comment: @ADyson I am not aware of how to set datatype in $.get() but $.getJSON() is a good solution

Comment: @ADyson also, its not actually browser related but somehow its the OS. Let me know if you figure out why that is.

Comment: "I am not aware of how to set datatype in $.get()" ...it's in the documentation... https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: So how do you know it's the O/S? You tried all possible browsers on Mac? safari, chrome, Firefox, and any others you can find online? They all have the same issue when run on Mac? And the cross-platform ones don't have the issue when run on any other o/s? You tested and confirmed all of this??

Comment: @ADyson Yes. In safari, firefox and chrome. It has to be something, any options i could think of does not make sense, but it has to the environment, including OS. Weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
    $.getJSON()

This method used to get JSON data using an AJAX HTTP GET request
Parameter url is must Required ,data is Optional,success(data,status,xhr) is Optional data is response from the server  and status is used for success,error,timeout and xhr is object XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution.
I still would like to know why this discrepancy occurs, if you find out let me know.

Comment: $.get() get method is response data based on header data type . $.get( "url", function( data ) {
  
}, "json" );  alternative  $.getJSON() method

Comment: Oh. So if I don't set the header datatype to json it will get me string. But, i ran my code in windows and linux system as well, and I did not need to set the header datatype to json, and the output there is still json whereas in mac its always string. This is what is confusing.